# Why Can't JVM Find Postgresql JDBC Driver?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure, leiningen

I know this question has been asked before, but existing answers do not help.

Existing answers tend to either tell you to put postgresql-.jar in /path/to/db/lib/, which I did; or center around MySQL. I've tried > 5 different answers and nothing is helping.

Here's what I'm running at the Clojure REPL:

```
(require '[next.jdbc :as jdbc])
(def db {:dbtype "postgres" :dbname "whatever" :user "whoever" :password "yeahright"})
(jdbc/get-connection db)
```

And I get this error:

```
Execution error (SQLException) at java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection (DriverManager.java:702).
 No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/<db_name>
```

I know where postgresql-42.2.12.jar is located on my computer, and I used :classpath-add to add that path in project.clj. I have double checked the syntax of the URL and it's correct so far as I can tell.

Java version:

```
  $ java -version
  java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

  $ lein -version
  Leiningen 2.9.1 on Java 10.0.1 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

I have the same problem on Ubuntu & Mac. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: i thought you just need to put the driver to your lein `:deps` : .. `[org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.12"]` . always works for me.

Comment: post your project.clj file

Comment: @leetwinski Can you move your comment to an answer? That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the `next.jdbc` **Getting Started** guide https://cljdoc.org/d/seancorfield/next.jdbc/CURRENT/doc/getting-started

"In addition, you will need to add dependencies for the JDBC drivers you wish to use for whatever databases you are using."

For `lein` that means adding the following to your `:dependencies` vector in `project.clj`:

```clj
[org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.10"]
```

(that's the latest version that `next.jdbc` is tested against at the time of writing, May 23rd, 2020)

Comment: Silly me. Must have missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `project.clj` contains an entry like this in

```
[org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.12"]
```

in the `:dependencies` vector.